# handling multiple buttons on a custom notification bar

Tags: android

I have a custom notification bar in my application that has 2 buttons. I found a way to make the buttons work by using contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent in my notification class and then handle the functionality in separate activity but I have a problem. Here is the code in Notification class.

```
 //Handle the button for showing bookmarks on custom notification
        Intent buttonsIntent2 = new Intent(context, NotificationBarButtonActivityHandler.class);
        buttonsIntent2.putExtra(PENDING_ACTION, REGISTER_BOOKMARK);
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notificationBarShowBookmarksButton, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, buttonsIntent2, 0));


        //Handle the button for adding bookmark on custom notification
        Intent buttonsIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationBarButtonActivityHandler.class);
        buttonsIntent.putExtra(PENDING_ACTION, SHOW_BOOKMARKS);
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notificationBarAddBookmarkFromChromeButton, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, buttonsIntent, 0));
```

The problem is that no matter which button is pressed, the button handler activity always receives REGISTER_BOOKMARK when I am pressing both button.

```
String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(NotificationBarService.PENDING_ACTION);
```

Could someone please explain to me why is this happening? Also, is this the optimal way to handle button presses in the notification bar?

Comment: Ok, I just figured out that putting different requestCode values (2nd argument in PendingIntent.getActivity call) fixes the problem. I am still curious as to why it does not work with the same request code since pendingIntent should be called on 2 different button presses.